# How to set minimum screen aspect ratio which app is supported in Google Play?

Tags: android, android-studio

The app should **not** support the devices with aspect ratio less than 1.7

How to set **minimum** screen aspect ratio which app is supported **in Google Play** (API 19+)?

**UPDATE:** The necessity of these restrictions is not discussed. 
The question is how to implement it (if it's possible)?
[image]

Comment: You can set maximum aspect ratio to restrict app distribution but not otherwise: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution

Comment: You content should scale instead of handling it by restricting aspect ratio. e.g. as you action bar size reduces your bottom bar should also reduce its size accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `DisplayMetrics` and calculate aspect ratio, and from code level show unsupported device message after launching the app.

To calculate aspect ratio, use below code:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float aspectRatio = (float)metrics.heightPixels / (float)metrics.widthPixels;
```

In your `Application.onCreate()`, if `aspectRatio < 1.7`, then show error layout.

Refer http://screensiz.es/phone for multiple devices height and width to calculate aspect ratio.

Comment: Thank You, but how to prevent installation into unsupported (for this restriction) devices?

Comment: On Android Q there is a new attribute "android:minAspectRatio"